# Can I prevent a rerender until both useState objects are updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why does a promise cause multiple rerenders?

My main issue is that `Forward` and `Goalie` functions are reliant on both `formation` and `starters`.

I am using a promise here to simulate my app making an api call to my backend service.

i.e.

```
  const pickFormation = (formation) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/games/${gameId}/starting-lineup/?formation=${formation}`, { headers:
      { Authorization: provider.token }
    })
      .then(res => {
        setStarters(res.data.starters)
        setFormation(formation)
      })
  }
```

Here is a code sample below used to recreate my issue. What is weird is that updating both states work if I delete the promise. 
With a promise is there a way to only render once after all state objects are updated?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {

  const [formation, setFormation] = useState('4-4-2');
  const [starters, setStarters] = useState({goalie: {name:'anthony'}});


  const updateFormation = (f) => {
    var promise1 = Promise.resolve();

    promise1.then(function () {
      setFormation(f)
      setStarters({ forward: { name: 'john' } });
    });


    // setFormation(f) this works perfectly with no promise. 
    // setStarters({ forward: { name: 'john' } });

  }

  const players = () => {
    switch(formation) {
      case '4-3-3':
        debugger;
        return <Forward starters={starters} />
      default: 
        return <Goalie starters={starters} />
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{formation}</p>
      <button onClick={() => updateFormation('4-3-3')}> update</button>
      {players()}
    </div>
  )
}

const Forward = ({starters}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{starters.forward.name[0]}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
const Goalie = ({starters}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{starters.goalie.name}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

If I delete the promise it renders no problem. If the promise is there i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: you are setting `starters` to `{ forward: { name: 'john' } }` and then trying to access `starters.goalie.name`

Comment: The issue is not with the Promise. You're not handling the formation and starters state correctly. Keep this state isolated from each other. Please refer @BoyWithSilverWings comment above.

Comment: How can I keep the state isolated from each other if they are dependent on one another? If I update just `formation` I will get the same error as above. They need to be updated at the same time in order for The `Forward` component to render correctly